# Debug Runtime of Visual Studio 2013 with QtAddIn in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

After completely removing previous Visual Studios versions, I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I then immediately added `qt-addin` from the built-in extension tool and tried to convert and compile a Qt project I had.

While compiling in release mode there is no problem but whenever I try to compile a debug version I have

> missing MSVCP120D.dll / MSVCR120D.dll

The problem only seems to happen with Qt projects.

I understand these DLLs are debug runtime files for VC2013, do you know how to force the use of the new DLLs or any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: If you don't want to have problems, you need to install msvc 2013 compiler. It is possible to use it with 2015 studio. It may cause unpredictable errors if you mix binaries that are build with different compilers (your project - 2015, Qt - 2013).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Qt5 with Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413617/setting-up-qt5-with-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

There is no redistributable MS VC runtime package for debug builds. Those only exist [for release builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx).

Install Visual Studio 2013 on a PC and copy the needed DLLs

```
C:\windows\system32\msvcr120d.dll
C:\windows\system32\msvci120.dll
C:\windows\system32\msvcp120d.dll
```

to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your toolset to 2015 in VS project properties and use Qt dlls built by/with VS2015 (afaik there's none being distributed and you have to build by your own)